# Prove using Taylor's Theorem: $1-\cos(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{x^2}{n^2}-\cos\theta(x_n,n)\frac{x^3}{6n^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

let $F_n(x)=n^2(1-\cos(\frac{x}{n}))$. I am asked to prove that this converges pointwise to limit function $F$ on a set $S$. In this case using geogebra, I see that it converges to $F=x^2$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

From the solutions manual, I found they got this using Taylor's theorem,
$1-\cos(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{x^2}{n^2}-\cos\theta(x_n,n)\frac{x^3}{6n^3}$
where $\theta(x_n,n)$ is between $0$ and $\frac{x}{n}$

Furthermore, they state that $|F_n(x)-x^2|\leq \frac{x^4}{24n^2}$.

How can I show,

$1-\cos(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{x^2}{n^2}-\cos\theta(x_n,n)\frac{x^3}{6n^3}$
and $|F_n(x)-x^2|\leq \frac{x^4}{24n^2}$.

What I have so far:

$1-\cos(\frac{x}{n})=1-\cos(\frac{a}{n})+\sin(\frac{a}{n})*(\frac{1}{n})*(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{a}{n})^2+\cos(\frac{a}{n})*(\frac{1}{n})*(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{a}{n})^3$....

How would I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $h>0$. Integrating by parts three times, one has
$$
\begin{align}
\cos h-1&=\int_0^h-\sin t\:dt
\\&=\left[(h-t) \frac{}{}\sin t\right]_0^h-\int_0^h (h-t)\cos t\:dt
\\&=\color{red}{0}+\left[\frac{(t-h)^2}{2}\cdot\cos t\right]_0^h+\int_0^h \frac{(t-h)^2}{2}\cdot\sin t\:dt
\\&=-\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac12\int_0^h (t-h)^2\cdot\sin t\:dt
\\&=-\frac{h^2}{2}+\left[\frac{(t-h)^3}{6}\cdot\sin t\right]_0^h-\int_0^h \frac{(t-h)^3}{6}\cdot\cos t\:dt
\\&=-\frac{h^2}{2}+\color{red}{0}-\int_0^h \frac{(t-h)^3}{6}\cdot\cos t\:dt
\end{align}
$$ or

> $$
> \cos h=1-\frac{h^2}{2}+\int_0^h \frac{(h-t)^3}{6}\cdot\cos t\:dt
> $$

then one may use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) for definite integrals to conclude.